# What exactly is <T> in the following method declaration?

Tags: java, generics

I'll admit that parameterized classes and methods combined with extends and super confuse the heck out of me. That said, I would appreciate if someone could explain why the following doesn't work, and direct me to a definitive guide to understanding these things.

Here's a barebones coding of my problem. In my main class:

```
public class App
{

    public <T extends Object> boolean isNull(T obj)
    {
        return obj == null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
 }
```

In my JUnit test class I have:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestClass1
{
    @Test
    public void shouldBeNull()
    {
        App theApp = new App();
        org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(theApp.isNull(new String())); //eclipse flags this line
    }
}
```

Eclipse warns me that the method isNull(String) is undefined for App. I was under the impression that in my definition of isNull, I'm telling it that any instance of T should be regarded as an object, and since String is an object, this should be OK. Obviously that's not the case. Please enlighten me. Thanks. And for what it's worth, I added the "extends Object" as a modification to the original method definition thinking this would help, but it didn't. A thousand thank you's to whoever can make what should be obvious (but isn't), obvious.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Could you be using pre-Java-5 code compliance?

Comment: This line doesn't make much sense to me: `public <T extends Object> boolean isNull(T obj)` - could it be that you just need `public boolean isNull(Object obj)` and call it a day?

Comment: @ammoQ it's totally pointless but should compile and run just fine.

Comment: Works for me... (Used just a standalone console app instead of a JUnit test, but it's the same thing.)

Comment: @ammoQ I thought this would prevent passing primitives like int or boolean to the method. Seems superfluous, but I'm as much trying to get a handle on parameterization as anything, hence the method signature. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Mena...using 1.8 compliance.

Comment: *"direct me to a definitive guide to understanding these things"* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/, http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Comment: *"using 1.8 compliance."* Try calling it like this: `theApp.<String>isNull(new String())`, also try updating to the newest version(s).